# Visual Studio Microsoft .Net Framework Exception Occured in w3wp.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-7

I am having a problem with my Visual Studio 2013 as I am continuously getting a pop up message on my screen with this message

> Visual Studio Just In Time Debugger An Unhandled Microsoft .Net Framework Exception Occured in w3wp.exe.

But disappears when I stop ASP.NETv4.0 application pool from IIS Manager.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.!!!

Comment: One of your ASP.NET applications is throwing an error and crashing the app pool.

Comment: @heavyd...I have observe that as i am getting this exception the app pool is still running.

Comment: I recently wrote an article that can help you to fine the cause of the crash - http://jockstothecore.com/an-unhandled-exception-in-w3wp-exe/